# How to match a word with no special character at front and back

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a word which has no special characters attached at both front and back.
The regex I have written is `/\btest\b/gi`                                                        I have added two word boundaries at front and back for matching the exact word.
The sample text is :

> This is a test.
> The testing was good.
> The tester was bad.
> package.test.com
> skkg@test.com
> Regex-test-is tough
> "rm/_HOST@DEV.HADOOP.R1-CORE.R1.TEST.NET&quot
> /Users/dattem/Desktop/DevCenter/test/ssl/
> The test is today.
> Name -test one

I want to match the **test** word of only first and last two lines.
https://regex101.com/r/AEfzUw/4

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It should only match the test word of line number one , nine and ten.

Comment: Currently its matching line 1,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10 as I have shown in the link.

Comment: So, split the text into lines, and run the regex against the first and last and last but one items.

Comment: Actually I will use it in some repositories to detect some particular text , so can't change the contextual text.

Comment: How can we answer your question without knowing which characters are "special characters"? Can the string begin `"test a..."` or end `"...a test"`?

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will match only the first and last 2 lines in your cases:

`(?<=[\s\t-])test(?=[\s\.\t])`

https://regex101.com/r/RCfs8l/1

It uses positive lookbehind and lookahead:

- `(?<=[\s\t-])` a space, tab or dash
- `test` test
- `(?=[\s\.\t])` followed by a space, a dot or tab

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/qCVP9t/1) does the trick:

```
(?<= )test\b|\btest(?= )
```

The word `test` either preceded or followed by a space. I don't think there is a way to avoid repeating the word `test` in the regex.